# Interpreting RTF issues

Tags: rtf

I have recently been tasked with building our own RTF to HTML Converter. With that, comes the RTF Interpreter piece.

I am using the 1.6 specifications found here:
http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec_7.html

and I have a question directed at the RTF experts out there:
Is "Paragraph Property Inheritance" considered to be "stack-able" or is it more of a First In First Out?

My question basically stems from an RTF specification rule that states:

```
"If the \pard control word is not present, the current paragraph inherits 
all paragraph properties defined in the previous paragraph."
```

Example:

```
\pard\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\par
\li720\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20 This is indented.\par
\li0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20This is left justified not indented.\par
```

should this then be interpreted like this (stack)?

- line 1 style + line 1 text
- line 1 style + line 2 style + line 2 text
- line 1 style + line 2 style + line 3 style + line 3 text

```
\pard\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\par
\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\li720\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20 This is indented.\par
\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\li720\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\li0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20This is left justified not indented.\par
```

Or rather like this (First In First Out)?

- line 1 style + line 1 text
- line 1 style + line 2 style + line 2 text
- line 2 style + line 3 style + line 3 text

```
\pard\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\par
\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\li720\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20 This is indented.\par
\ssparaaux0\s0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20\li0\ql\plain\f0\fs24\lang4105\hich\f6\dbch\f6\loch\f6\cf2\fs20This is left justified not indented.\par
```

Strangely, depending on which word processor i am using, these 3 lines get interpreted much differently from one to another. So what is the official thing to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the previous \pard tag, all paragraph tags are accumulative. So if no \pard is used for the current paragraph, then it would inherit all paragraph tags found until the last paragraph, plus adds it own, and so forth.